# ANDROID: Get next item from listview to editText after 1st item is saved

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

**What I have: (1st Functionality)**
I have a listview activity populated with items from JSON url. I have another activity where I get the listItem to editText field and then click "save", which saves the value to dB.

**What I additionally want: (2nd Functionality)**
When I click save, rather than going back to listview and select next listItem, I want the editText to fill the new listItem for me. But I am making errors in every step.

Below is the code that I have for 1st Functionality. I know it is just few lines to achieve the 2nd functionality but struggling with that.

> The problem here is I cannot call the list String variable from one
>   activity to another and assign position or a counter to it. Suggest me
>   what to change here.

MainActivity.java **(Class containing ListView populated with item from json url)**

```
package com.example.app.listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> tutorialList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final static String URL = "-----json------url----file";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new FetchDataTask().execute(URL);

    }

    private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result= null;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

            try {

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                // convert inputstream to string
                if(inputStream != null){
                    result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    Log.i("App", "Data received:" +result);

                }
                else
                    result = "Failed to fetch data";

                return result;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
            //parse the JSON data and then display
            parseJSON(dataFetched);
        }


        private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            String result = "";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;

            inputStream.close();
            return result;

        }

        private void parseJSON(String data){

            try{
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

                int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

                for(int i=0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String postTitle = jsonChildNode.getString("codeid");
                    tutorialList.add(postTitle);
                }

                // Get ListView object from xml
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                // Define a new Adapter
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tutorialList);

//                 Assign adapter to ListView
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                                Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFlowerInfo.class);
                                intent.putExtra("Code", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
        });

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("App", "Error parsing data" +e.getMessage());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

editText.java **(class containing editText field and save to dB)**

```
package com.example.app.listview;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class AddFlowerInfo extends AppCompatActivity  {
    EditText editText; //non editable codeid <<----<<----<<----<<--<<---<<1
    private static final String TAG = "AddFlowerInfo";

    Button savedata;
    String noneditcode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_flower_info);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeid);
        savedata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveflowerinfo);

        final String Codeholder = getIntent().getStringExtra("Code");
        editText.setText(Codeholder);
      }

    public void dataflowerinfo(View view){

        noneditcode = editText.getText().toString();


        String method = "FlowerInfo";
        BackgroundTask2 backgroundTask2 = new BackgroundTask2(this);
        backgroundTask2.execute(method, noneditcode);
        finish();

    }
```

**UPDATE AddFlowerInfo.java (OnCreate) and (OnClick)**

```
public class AddFlowerInfo extends AppCompatActivity  {
    EditText editText; //non editable codeid <<----<<----<<----<<--<<---<<1
    private static final String TAG = "AddFlowerInfo";

    Button savedata;
    int i=0;

    String noneditcode;
    int pos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_flower_info);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeid);
        savedata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveflowerinfo);

        Intent i =getIntent();
        final ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
          pos = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

//        final String Codeholder = getIntent().getStringExtra("Code");
        editText.setText(list.get(pos));

        savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(AddFlowerInfo.this, AddFlowerInfo.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                ++pos;
                if(pos<=list.size()-1)

                    list.get(pos);

            }
        });
```

Comment: so are passing one string at a time to AddFlowerInfo activity.right?

Comment: yes @JinsLukose

Comment: so you have to save all data to  string array and pass it to AddFlowerInfo activity

Comment: Yes @JinsLukose , but I am not able to figure it out how to do it?

Comment: Can you write it for me, Because cannot understand that part

Comment: Instead of AddFlowerInfo as activity, why don't you make it a fragment. Show it inside/over the MainActivity. Use an interface to pass data to fragment from activity after every save.

Comment: @Arvind please wait a while

Comment: @Arvind why are you starting this 
Intent intent =  new Intent(AddFlowerInfo.this, AddFlowerInfo.class);
activity again?

Comment: remove this:
Intent intent =  new Intent(AddFlowerInfo.this, AddFlowerInfo.class);
                startActivity(intent);

from onClick

Comment: because I want to redirect to the same activity page after button click

Comment: i removed it and when I click button it is doing nothing @SurajVaishnav

Comment: Please change list.get(pos);   =>  editText.setText(list.get(pos)) in onClick method

Comment: conceptually I thought after 1st item in edit text is saved, again the same activity should open with the next item in the list. So I did it, Now i removed it, No exception and error but the button click is not responding

Comment: @SurajVaishnav in the editText field the values are changing after I click but the data is not being saved in database

Comment: the flow goes like this when you click on submit button you should have to add code to save data to db if it is saved successfully then you can get new next item data and this process will goes until you reach at last item.

Comment: I guess it is because of android button on click method that I wrote to save data in dB. i think `savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}` and `public void dataflowerinfo(View view){...}` are clashed?

Comment: before adding this `savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}` the data was saved to dB and returned to listView. But now the data is not being saved but the values in editText are canging when I click them

Comment: @SurajVaishnav any suggestion or help?

Comment: Can you tell me what can I do to save the data to dB, no exception at all?

Comment: I can't give you suggestion, I am not aware of your code.

Comment: okay, thanks for you time, that is all the code I have in the question. May it is not saving because e have changed the listview items from string to array?  I think so maybe, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your data from activity like this

```
 ArrayList<String> tutorialList = new ArrayList<String>();  
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Second.class);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", tutorialList);
 startActivity(intent);
```

To retrive at AddFlowerInfo

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Then as you are retrieving data from list using position ,each time after saving call data at next position

Comment: One concern I see with this approach is that when the user returns to the previous activity it will have old/stale data, not the one that's been edited.

Comment: @Kaustuv that's correct but that can be handled if he is not calling the Json data once again rather get the data from database

Comment: @JinsLukose if I do this, in AddFlowerInfo, It is showing error on line 
`editText.setText(list)`. It is saying `cast parameter to 'java.lang.CharSequence'`, Then after I did, the app is showing an exception like     `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app.listview/com.example.app.listview.AddFlowerInfo}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence`

Comment: @JinsLukose can you help me out?

Comment: the below answer is actually correct. anyway let me check

Answer (score 0):

You need to send complete array to `AddFlowerInfo` with the position, so change your `onItemClick` code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFlowerInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", i);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("array",tutorialList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Now in `AddFlowerInfo`:

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> tutorialList = i.getStringArrayListExtra("array");
        int pos=i.getIntExtra("position",0);
```

Use this position to get item from `tutorialList`.

To update data when user gets back to previous activity, place this code:

```
 new FetchDataTask().execute(URL);
```

into `onResume` method.

**Update**

After saving first item to edit second item use:

```
++pos;
if(pos<=tutorialList.size()-1)
    editText.setText(tutorialList.get(pos)); 
else
 {
   // you are after last item do whatever you want
 }
```

Comment: Instead of fetching everytime in onResume, won't it be better to start AddFlowerInfo activity for result, then onActivityResult fetch data if result=OK. This will prevent unnecessary fetching of data, say when coming from screen unlock.

Comment: It is showing me error on line `editText.setText(list)`. Here edit Text is have the value of the item from list and the error is `Castparameter to java.lang.Charsequence` this error is in AddFlower class where we set the text to go in to editText field @SurajVaishnav

Comment: Yes, it is working, but after saving the 1st item, I want the editText to be filled with the 2nd item from list without going back to the listView. So to that should i use the button's object and can you explain about `new FetchDataTask().execute(URL);`,

Comment: like I mean after ,
`editText.setText(list.get(position));
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // What should I write here//
            }
        });`

Comment: Yes, but `tutorialList` is in MainActivity. So it will be unresolved symbol in AddFlowerInfo class

Comment: and `++pos;
tutorialList.get(pos);` this should be written in `setOnClistener` method?

Comment: You may not following my complete answer, if you check i am using tutorialList variable in AddFlowerInfo to get data sent from MainActivity. the thing whatever name of list(you are using varable name=> list) pass new index to get data.
yes this code will be in onClick

Comment: yeah i understood it now, But I got  `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 24, Size: 24` and I am afraid that in `Onresume`,   `new FetchDataTask().execute(URL);` are unresolved, I mean what should i write inside FetchDataTask().

Comment: put if(pos<=tutorialList.size()-1) before tutorialList.get(pos); as i have updated my answer

Comment: @SurajVaishnav Actually the thing is since I am using 'position'in 'OnClick' it is asking me to declare it as `final array` and if I do that in `if` Statement, it is showing on line `if(...)` as `Operator '<=' cannot be applied to int[] and int`, So conflict!!!

Comment: make position global variable so it will not restrict you to declare final, try it and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: This is the exception :

   `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erawan.app.listview/com.example.app.listview.AddFlowerInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: And this is my code

`savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(AddFlowerInfo.this, AddFlowerInfo.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                ++pos;
                if(pos<=list.size()-1)

                    list.get(pos);

            }
        });`

Comment: where have you initialized list?

Comment: same as position, global

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please see it in UPDATE AddFlowerInfo.java (OnCreate) and (OnClick)
in question